# Locking in JpaRepository Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, locking

Is it possible in spring boot to take lock on whole table instead of rows?
So far I saw only `EntityManager.lock(*)` but this locks on only given records.

I have a situation in which I have to delete all records of a table and fill that table again with records, For this transaction, I want to take a lock on the table so that no other process reads from this table.

I am using JpaRepository.

Answer (score 0):

Use `entityManager.lock(user,LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`

It will take lock on whole table and no other transaction can read, update or delete from the table.

Hope it helps..!!